# .net core 5 not binding XML model

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building an API in net core 5 that has to accept XML and JSON as input and output.
My startup looks like:

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true)
     .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
     .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
      .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
      {
          opt.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
          opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
       });
```

My class looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class LoginModel
{
    public LoginModel() { }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

My controller:

```
[Route("Auth")]
[ApiController]
[Consumes("application/xml", new string[] { "application/json" })]
public class AuthController : Controller
{
     public AuthController (){...}
     
    [HttpPost("login")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
         //the model parameter is always null when passing xml
    }
}
```

XML to test:

```
<LoginModel>
    <Username>admin</Username>
    <Password>admin123</Password>
</LoginModel>
```

I am passing`Content-Type as application/xml` and `Accept as application/xml`.

Do any of you see a problem? I am trying to get it fixed since yesterday.
I always get a 400 response with message `An error occurred while deserializing input data.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
services.AddControllers(options => 
        { 
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I still don't know why I need to add Input/Output formatters to the AddControllers if I already add them using extension methods. This is a question for another day.

Comment: Being picky, I don't think this is a complete answer, because it does not explain why it is correct.

Comment: Add an answer with explanations and I'll accept yours.